# How to set device height and width for a bar chart in android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova

I am using phonegap to build my app.I am using flot to create charts.
here is my javascript code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>    
<div id="pie-example" style="width:300px;height:200px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pie_chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code i am giving the width and height of the bar graph.I want to give device height and width.How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. We have to set the viewport like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=default-width; user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did you want to give the bar graph the same size as the device? I'm having the same issue now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895663/flot-on-android-how-to-fit-the-screen-size